# Select lists with specific numbering style

Tags: vba, ms-word

When using the following condition

```
Set r = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).range
If r.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(1).NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman Then
```

I get

> Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

I managed to create a similar macro for lists with specific bullets using `AscW` check, but here already wasted a whole day and still no working result.

What an I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Is it possible to use values from [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213951%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead of wd-names? For wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman that would be "2" according to the table.

Comment: You arwe checking the value of `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(1).NumberStyle`. The error you get means that one of the objects in that chained calls is `nothing`. Hard to tell which one it is, but by breaking up the statement, you could figure that out yourself. Makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Indeed there has been nothing returning for non-list `Paragraphs`. I figured it out thanks to your comment and by means of `Debug.Print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using class `ListParagraphs` instead of `Paragraphs` will make it work both with wd-names and their values.